# Create directory based on current date

Tags: php

At the moment I have a directory called `showcase` in my root folder. When uploading a file, I want to check if a directory exists and if not, create it based on the current date, and then move the file to that folder.

```
$dateYear = date('Y');
$dateMonth = date('M');
$dateDay = date('d');

if (!is_dir("/showcase/$dateYear/$dateMonth/$dateDay")) {
    mkdir("/showcase/$dateYear/$dateMonth/$dateDay");         
}

if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc,"/showcase/$dateYear/$dateMonth/$dateDay/$newName")){

    // stuff

}
```

`$newName` is the file's name, e.g. `SajdaT.jpg`. This code doesn't do anything for me. How can I create something that does what I want?

e.g.

`/showcase/2015/09/02` create if it doesn't exist, then move a file to it like

`/showcase/2015/09/02/SajdaT.jpg`

Comment: Whenever working with files, check permissions first. Look at the error logs and see if there are errors about permissions. Almost every time someone says "It not do nothing", it is actually the case that it is spitting out plenty of errors to the error log.

Comment: The `is_dir` and `mkdir` lines look more like URLs to me, do you really have a folder called `showcase` in the root of your file system? (i.e. you're aware you're using absolute paths, right?) O_o

Comment: `PHP Warning:  mkdir(): No such file or directory in /home/*****/public_html/****/upload.php on line 91`

Comment: @frosty You probably also want the 3rd arg of mkdir to be true to recursively create the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pass recursive attribute as true with the method.

<?php

// Desired folder structure
$structure = './dir1/dir2/dir3/';

// To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
// to mkdir() must be specified.

if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}

// ...
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting `mkdir(): Permission denied` - this is on a shared host

Comment: yeah may be. just check the permissions that you have as a user on showcase directory. You need to have write permissions to create one.